# Form doesn't save but returns 200

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create an object of item and save it to the database through a form i wrote. Right now I'm able to update it from my form also admin panel works i can create item from there. However, create form not saving. When i click the button, it refreshes the page, returns 200 in terminal but doesn't save it. I'm putting every part of it, i checked a lot but not seeing any error.

edit: i tried function based view, same result. But as i understood, the problem is about picture.

This is my model.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='items')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_pictures')
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='category')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My url

```
 path('item/create/', ItemCreateView.as_view(), name='item-create'),
```

My view

```
class ItemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Item
fields = ['name', 'description', 'price', 'picture', 'is_available', 'category', 'slug' ]
template_name = 'item/item_update.html'
success_url = '/'
```

Success url return home page, but form only refreshes

And form

```
class ItemCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'price', 'picture', 'is_available', 'category', 'slug']
```

Lastly template just in case

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'item-create' %}" method="POST" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Apparently i forgot enctype="multipart/form-data" in template. I solved it. Thanks for everyone reading:)

Comment: Please, instead of writing a comment post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i forgot enctype="multipart/form-data" in template. The problem is solved.